# Jquery-mobile data-role=content clarification

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

What exactly is the **purpose** for the `data-role="content"`?
I'm testing out a few things like animations/transitions etc and so, when I removed that from the container div that had the content, everything still worked.

For example if I do this:

```
<div id="secondPage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>This is page 2 </h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
       <p>This is page 2 with some regular text here.</p>
       <p><a href="#firstPage" data-direction="reverse">Go to first page.</a></p><br/>
    </div> 
</div>
```

it works as it should, but if I then remove the `data-role="content"` part
and make it for example like this:

```
  <div id="secondPage" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
        <h1>This is page 2 </h1>
        </div>

        <div>
           <p>This is page 2 with some regular text here.</p>
           <p><a href="#firstPage" data-direction="reverse">Go to first page.</a></p><br/>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

it still works so I'm a bit hazy as to the need for it. So whats the point of it?

Comment: The data-role="content" is simply used so that jQuery knows where your content is in relation the the header and footer (as they may well be fixed).

Comment: what do you mean fix, is something broken about it?

Comment: fixed (attached to the bottom or the top).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `data-role="content"` is simply a convention and isn't required.

To quote the [jQuery site](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html):

> "Although the page structure outlined above is a recommended approach for a standard web app built with jQuery Mobile, the
>   framework is very flexible with document structure. The page, header,
>   content, and footer data-role elements are optional and are mostly
>   helpful for providing some basic formatting and structure. The page
>   wrapper that used to be required for auto-initialization to work is
>   now optional for single page documents, so there isn't any required
>   markup at all. For a web page with a custom layout, all of these
>   structural elements can be omitted and the Ajax navigation and all
>   widgets will work just like they do in the boilerplate structure."

While they are not required, they are used by jQuery to apply classes at pagecreate,
A div with `data-role="content"` for example will have the class `.ui-content` added to it.

Answer (score 1):

[JQueryMobile Transitions](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-transitions.html) are applied on the `data-role="page"` element and not `data-role="content"`

Comment: so then do i really need it, am i penalized in any way for not using it?

Comment: In my experience, the JQM designed page navigation and transition suffice for a mobile application flow... you can definitely add animation to child elements on your `page` with JQuery and/or CSS techniques.